# Запрет доступа к странице через iptables

Tags: linux, iptables

Господа, как запретить юзерам доступ к одной конкретной странице? Прописываю на роутере волшебную строчку, сооружённую методом гуглежа и стэковерфлоу, но результата нет.

Условия: только с 18 до 8 утра, только в будние дни, юзер с определённым mac.

Что тут некорректного?

`iptables -A OUTPUT -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -m time --timestart 18:00 --timestop 08:00 --weekdays Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri -p tcp -m string --string "/.+mydomain.com\/test.+/si" --algo regex -j DROP`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В протоколе HTTPS адрес странички зашифрован и его получить нет никакой возможности.

Единственное что может такое правило - это блокировать домен целиком при обращении с браузера с включенным SNI.

В случае http `-j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset` чтоб не страдать при отладке.

-A OUTPUT - это трафик исходящий от локального компьютера и класификатор  --mac-source тут не применим. Замените на `-A FORWARD` если блокируете на роутере или убирайте mac.

Comment: Даже в случае, если не используется https?

Comment: SNI скоро тоже зашифруют

Comment: может всё же HTTPS, а не HTTP?